# Simple variable is not defined reference error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

Just trying to print `h1.name` to console, but I'm receiving a `ReferenceError: h1 is not defined` error. It doesn't matter if I type 1, 2, or 3, still the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
function Hand(name, sChips) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sChips = sChips;
}

function start() {
var nHands = prompt("How many hands do you want to play?(1,2, or 3)");
var nHands = Number(nHands);
    if (0 < nHands < 4 ) {
        if (nHands === 1) {
            var h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 150000);
        }
        else if (nHands === 2) {
            var h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 75000);
            var h2 = new Hand("Second Hand", 75000);
        }
        else if (nHands === 3) {
            var h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 50000);
            var h2 = new Hand("Second Hand", 50000);
            var h3 = new Hand("Third Hand", 50000);
        }
    else {
        start();
    }
    }
};

start();

console.log(h1.name)
```

Comment: The `h1` varibale only exists inside the `start()` function, it's local.

Comment: This isn't ideal var declaration anyway. You should be declaring your variables at the start of the function. JavaScript variables are only function-scoped, so declaring variables inside an `if-else` block is meaningless

Comment: just return what you want to have access to:     return{h1: h1, h2:h2} and reference like this: start().h1.name; You'd do the return before last "}" in your start function.

Comment: @jamesemanon since it's a collection of `Hand` objects, an array is probably a better choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `h1` outside the `start` function, so that it will visible to the code outside the `start` function.

```
var h1, h2, h3;

function start() {
    var nHands=parseInt(prompt("How many hands do you want to play?(1,2 or 3)"));
    ...
    if (nHands === 1) {
        h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 150000);
    ...
```

**Notes:**

1. This is not python, so this condition might not work as intended

   ```
   if (0 < nHands < 4 ) {
   ```

   what you need is

   ```
   if (nHands < 4 && nHands > 0) {
   ```
2. You are declaring `nHands` twice, which is not necessary, you can convert the input data to the number like this

   ```
   var nHands=parseInt(prompt("How many hands do you want to play?(1,2 or 3)"));
   ```
3. It is always good to include an `else` condition, to your if-else ladder.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. the `h1` variable is declared within the `start` function which means that when the OP tries to print `h1` it is out of scope

Answer (score 1):

you could also just stuff the hand objects in a hash, like so. 
Caveat: this just enables your "h1,h2,h3" to be accessible like you expect. poster "thefourtheye" has given a robust/clear idea of probably where you want to go.

```
    function Hand(name, sChips) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sChips = sChips;
}
var h = {}; //global h obj
function start() {
var nHands = prompt("How many hands do you want to play?(1,2, or 3)");
var nHands = Number(nHands);
    if (0 < nHands < 4 ) {
        if (nHands === 1) {
            h.h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 150000);
        }
        else if (nHands === 2) {
            h.h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 75000);
            h.h2 = new Hand("Second Hand", 75000);
        }
        else if (nHands === 3) {
            h.h1 = new Hand("First Hand", 50000);
            h.h2 = new Hand("Second Hand", 50000);
            h.h3 = new Hand("Third Hand", 50000);
        }
    else {
        start();
    }
    }

};

    start();
    console.log(h.h2.name, h['h2'].name)
```